# How to send a array in MultipartRequest in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, postman

this is i am testing my api using postman as array

[image]

but how can i send array using MultipartRequest

```
var uri = Uri.parse(Constants.BASEURL + Constants.KEYEORD_CREATE_TENANACY);
  Map<String, String> headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": token
    };
   var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
   request.headers.addAll(headers);
   request.fields['property_usage'] = property_use;
   request.fields['unit_id'] = unitlist;               // here i want unit_id to array
   var response = await request.send();
   print("Tenancy Add Result: ${response.statusCode}");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     print(response);
    }
```

Comment: Did you got any approach to the issue?

Answer (score 3):

'''

```
request.fields['unit_id[n]'] = "${arrUnitlist[n]}";
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrUnitlist; i++){
  request.fields['unit_id[$i]'] = '${arrUnitlist[i]}';
}
```

'''

works for me

Answer (score 2):

it is possible just open Multipart defination and change final fields = <String,String> to final fields = <String,dynamic> or any other datatype you want.

Comment: Hi Turaab. Thanks for your answer, but it is not very clear. Can you not provide the code? Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your array data of `unit_id` like this:

```
var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
request.headers.addAll(headers);
request.fields['property_usage'] = property_use;
request.fields['unit_id[0]'] = "unitlist1";
request.fields['unit_id[1]'] = "unitlist2";
request.fields['unit_id[2]'] = "unitlist3";
var response = await request.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible , `request.fileds` is a `Map<String,String>`, So you have to provide a `String` , not an array. Is there a specific reason that you are using a `MultipartRequest` ? It is used to send files to servers , if you are not doing that you can use simple `http` functions like `put` and I think that would be more relevant for you  . Get more details from official docs for  [put](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/put.html) and [MultipartRequest](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html).

Comment: yes i am sending image to server ! how to solve this issue